# MySql Update innerJoin

Tags: mysql, sql

Como realizo esta consulta:

Tengo 3 tablas `A` `B` y `C`

La tabla `A` está relacionada con los ID'S de la Tabla `B`.

Necesito sacar los ids de `B` cuyo `xcampo` sea igual a `xcampo` de `C`.

ahora se debe  actualizar `xcampo` de `A` que contenga los ID's que acabo de Obtener de la tabla `B`.

---

Yo ya lo hago de la siguiente Manera, hago un `INNER JOIN` de `B` y `C` , exporto esos ID´S y luego actualizo la tabla `A` con un `csv` de esos ID´s pero quisiera saber si alguien pudiera tener una fórmula más compacta y rápida.

Apliqué la solución elegida como la correcta ( y funcionó perfecto)  mi código personal quedó así:

```
UPDATE pai_titulo AS a, 
     (
        SELECT
             pai.id ,update2.decreto
        FROM
            pai
        INNER JOIN
            update2
        On update2.cedula = pai.numero_documento
    ) AS b
set a.requerido_decreto_pep = b.decreto 
WHERE  a.id_pai = b.id
```

Comment: por mas compacta te refieres a un solo query? podes poner lo que ya tenes escrito, es dificil relacionar lo que pedis solo leyendo la descripcion.

Comment: Hola Andress. La pregunta es la pregunta y la respuesta es la respuesta .. Edita la pregunta para mostrar el codigo que tenias antes de la solucion obtenida, no el codigo tras la resolucion. Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adivinando un poco sobre la estructura de tus tablas, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE table.a AS a, 
     (
        SELECT
            id,xcampo
        FROM
            B
        INNER JOIN
            C
        USING (xcampo)
    ) AS b
set a.xcampo = b.xcampo 
WHERE
        a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Buenas Jorge, buena respuesta ... pero como tu dices, has tenido que adivinar. es porque la pregunta es demasiado amplia. Puede que hayas acertado o puede que no. ha de especificar mas para que podamos contestar. Si la contestas y resulta que le resuelves el problema, no se esforzará más en su pregunta y favorecemos que no se esfuercen en las preguntas. Perdona por el tochazo hahaha Un saludo

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, aun así en la imaginación, pues así, todo siempre resulta. Se ve bastante buena tu respuesta.

Comment: Justamente le atinaste, Muchisimas Gracias , que pena que no haya puesto mejor la estructura de tablas, muchas gracias, buen día.

Comment: @AndressBlend estás a tiempo de mejorar tu pregunta. Incluso despues de solucionada siempre se incita a mejorar. Recuerda darle a aceptar como solucion dandole click al tick de la izquierda. un saludo !

Comment: @AndressBlend si, favor de editar la pregunta, después servirá para otros. Saludos